# Eclipse WindowBuilder can't change value

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, field, windowbuilder

I am working with the Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 2018-12 (4.10) on Ubuntu 18.04 with the JDK 1.8 (202) on a Java project, I have installed WindowBuilder components for drag and drop designing with Java Swing Components:

[image: List of components installed in eclipse software]

I can successfully add components but can't change any field value like bounds value or text value in Ubuntu eclipse I have worked on it in windows and able to change there but here is this bug.

I've checked the code and working with windows eclipse WindowBuilder

Not working even in a new project.

[image: Properties Image]

Comment: Is this the default dark theme? Does all not work: clicking in the field, clicking on the square on the right side in the field, and via keyboard (e.g. tap to navigate and space to toggle a checkbox)?

Comment: Yes this is default dark theme of eclipse and i am aware about the basic of windowBuilder and working on with windows but in linux eclipse can't edit by mouse or by keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and for me the solution was to download last good build directly from update site instead of Eclipse Marketplace.

https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php